# I'm tring to create very simple wordpress plugin but my javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I had already connected the `javascript` file

Enqueue script function is:

```
function wpplugin_admin_scripts(){
   wp_enqueue_script(
    'myplugin-admin',
    WPPLUGIN_URL.'admin/js/eylonplugin-admin.js',
    ['jquery'],
    time()
   );

 }
 add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpplugin_admin_scripts', 100);
```

But while I'm trying to style some attributes I can't.

This is the function that I'm adding `HTML` to my plugin page :

```
 function my_plugin_plugin_html(){ ?>
    
    <div id="wrap container">
        <h3> Plugin Header </h3>
    
        <form method="post" action='options.php'>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>
            <?php settings_fields('my_plugin_option_group'); ?>
            <label for="my_plugin_field_plugin">Top bar color</label>
            <input name="my_plugin_field" id="my_plugin_field_plugin" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('my_plugin_field')?>"><br>        
            <div>
            <?php submit_button('my_plugin I love you');?> 
        </form>
        <h2 id="js_checking">my_plugin<span class="selected_output"></span></h2>
        <script> </script>
        </div>
        <h3>My color is red</h3>
        <button id="try_me">Try me!</button>
    <?php
}
```

Here I'm trying to style my h3 attribute but nothing happens. But the alert is working.

```
$("h3").css("color","red");
alert("Hello world");
```

Comment: What's the reason for using JavaScript instead of CSS to style the elements?

Comment: I just want to check my javascript, I also tried to use .hide() and it's not working either.

Comment: There is still too little to go on. Are you encountering any errors? What happens when you `console.log($('h3'))`? Is jQuery using no-conflict mode? (which means that you need to use `jQuery('h3').css('color', 'red');` instead of the `$` symbol.

Comment: Maybe this is because of the `!important` rule, try other style for other tag and check the result

Comment: Thank you.I found the problem I used this code > jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("h3").css("color", "red");
});

Comment: Is there a way to change the jQuery to the regular dollar ($) symbol?

Comment: @EylonS In generell if you want to learn building web stuff for the future try to avoid using jQuery: https://flaviocopes.com/jquery/

JavaScript is super powerful and you do not require jquery today.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jquery code with as below so you can add codes without using jQuery instead of $:

```
(function ($) {

YOUR CODES HERE

})(jQuery);
```